# How to share Animated Gifs with Facebook SDK Triggered Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK 2.5 to generate a share dialog. What's odd is that when the share is an animated gif, it doesn't go through with animation intact and instead shows as the first frame static.

I've tried also without using the SDK using FB's URL method, with sharer.PHP on their side, and get the same result.

My first though was that Facebook simply doesn't allow animated Gifs through those routes, but giphy is proving me wrong. Although if you look at the open graph on a giphy share URL, they have a lot of off-label code in there.

Does anyone know if there is a Facebook sanctioned way to share an animated gif via a share dialog, or are we destined to have to 'hack this out.'

Comment: You are sure giphy are sharing gifs?

Answer (score 1):

Using `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=[YOURIMAGEURL]` works for me. Giphy.com also uses this method.

Example: [`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://gph.is/2aclqqC`](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://gph.is/2aclqqC)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than share dialog you can post on feed by the method `me/feed/` and put the gif url under the `link` object

example:

```
FB.api(
  'me/feed/',
  'POST',
  {
    message: 'This is a GIF',
    link: 'http://25.media.tumblr.com/08d54accc4beb56a50e752fd931c6b58/tumblr_mlsyqrzwWQ1s3g3ago1_400.gif'
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

Comment: Hmm seems to require an oAuth token from the user.